# Vector-to-direction method in Java

Tags: java, enum

I don't really have a problem, but my code bothers me, because I know it could be done in a much better way.

I have an `enum` of 4 directions: north west, north east, south east and south west. And I have a method that converts a vector to one of those directions. The method prefers North and East, so values of 0 would return those.

```
public enum Direction {
    NORTH_WEST, NORTH_EAST, SOUTH_EAST, SOUTH_WEST;

    public static Direction vectorToDirection(Vector2 vector) {
        if (vector.y >= 0) {
            if (vector.x >= 0) return NORTH_EAST;
            else return NORTH_WEST;
        } else {
            if (vector.x >= 0) return SOUTH_EAST;
            else return SOUTH_WEST;
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone can figure out a cleaner or more efficient method, I'd love to know!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Efficiency**

I don't think that can be improved. You're only using two if-statements. This is as efficient as it can get, I believe.

**Cleaner**

Depends on if you consider the conditional operator `?:` clean or not.

```
public static Direction vectorToDirection(Vector2 vector) {
    if (vector.y >= 0) {
        return vector.x >= 0 ? NORTH_EAST : NORTH_WEST;
    } else {
        return vector.x >= 0 ? SOUTH_EAST : SOUTH_WEST;
    }
}
```

This code does exactly the same as your previous code, it's just a different way of writing it.

In my opinion, it would be foolish to try and reduce it more than this. Be happy with this one. Good job.

Comment: If ternary statements make the code it cleaner, why not nest them to remove the if/else & have a single return?

Comment: @awashburn Because in my opinion, nested ternaries reduce readability.

Answer (score 12):

## Use Braces:

Consider using braces for more readable code:

> ```
> public static Direction vectorToDirection(Vector2 vector) {
>     if (vector.y >= 0) {
>         if (vector.x >= 0) return NORTH_EAST;
>         else return NORTH_WEST;
>     } else {
>         if (vector.x >= 0) return SOUTH_EAST;
>         else return SOUTH_WEST;
>     }
> }
> ```

Becomes (with eclipse <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>):

```
public static Direction vectorToDirection (Vector2 vector) {
     if (vector.y >= 0) {
         if (vector.x >= 0) {
             return NORTH_EAST;
         } else {
             return NORTH_WEST;
         }
      } else {
         if (vector.x >= 0) {
             return SOUTH_EAST;
         } else {
             return SOUTH_WEST;
         }
     }
}
```

And suddenly it becomes extremely obvious and readable what happens here.

### Naming:

Additionally I'd consider naming your method `fromVector()` instead. Compare:

```
Direction.vectorToDirection(someVector);
```

against

```
Direction.fromVector(someVector);
```

### Documentation:

When I see the implementation I know, but how would anyone outside know you prefer east > west and north > south? Write some JavaDoc. Example:

```
/**
* @param vector the 2-dimensional vector to be converted to a direction
* @returns The Direction. hereby North is preferred over South and 
* East is preferred over West. 
* Example: Direction.fromVector(new Vector2(0, 0)); will return NORTH_EAST
* Direction.fromVector(new Vector2(-1, 0)); will return SOUTH_EAST
*/
public static Direction fromVector(Vector2 vector) {
// ...
```

Comment: I think the style of using braces vs. in-line for if statements with only a single line is mostly a matter of taste. The "bug-prone" really only comes in if you put it on a new line, without braces. In-line with braces is also perhaps slightly more readable.

Comment: @Ben it may be my personal preference, but I find inlined if-blocks unreadable to the point of declaring it a code-obfuscation. It's so much harder to read the intent of these than if they are at least properly indented. And from that it's only a short step to add the braces, just to be safe and consistent.

Comment: @VapidLinus in what way is this not *"cleaner"* than your original solution? Is it not more obvious, don't the names fit the use-case more? What did you want to hear? Feel free to come to [chat]

Comment: I disagree with the 'braces' section for this specific case - the ternary solution reduces the (visible) nesting of conditionals, which is much cleaner - especially because this code is unlikely to change, except with maybe the return values switching if the OP decides at some point that `west > east`.